# order button in android

Tags: java, android

I want to order 5 button in the bottom of the screen that will with equal space all over the bottom of the screen (app). 
is there an command that will do it no matter the screen size?

basically I need to divided the screen at 5 & put the button in place.
I tried to do it custom button but it's look different from one screen to another.

thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: use a linear layout and use weight property to give them equal space

Answer (score 1):

You can use weight. Here's an example:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybtn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybtn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybtn3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Because all buttons have a `layout_weight` of 1, they are all sized equally. If one of them would be 2, is would be twice as big. This only works in `LinearLayout`. Make sure you have the width of the buttons set to `0dp`.